# Is this possible to use += to add a single value into two variables at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Following this logic :

```
a,b = 0,0
```

I was expecting this to work :

```
a,b += 1,1
SyntaxError: illegal expression for augmented assignment
```

so here i am.

Is there anyway to achieve this in one line ?

Comment: `a,b=0` is invalid as well

Comment: It should be `a=b=0` OR `a,b=0,0` and not `a,b=0`

Comment: Why not use vector of length 2 and interpret elements as a and b?

Comment: Or why not being explicit and just do `a += 1 ; b += 1`?

Comment: This is why i need to rest . Iv forgot the logic inside my question while typing it thnks A LOT Chris for pointing me in the right direction ...the bed .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned by others, you could combine two statements into one line as `a += 1; b += 1`.

But, if you prefer a single statement in the same "spirit" as `a, b = 0, 0` then try this:

```py
a, b = a + 1, b + 1
```

The way these assignments work is that a list of variables is assigned a list of values:

| variable | value |
| --- | --- |
| a | 0 |
| b | 0 |

→ `a = 0; b = 0` → `a, b = 0, 0`

| variable | value |
| --- | --- |
| a | a + 1 |
| b | b + 1 |

→ `a = a + 1; b = b + 1` → `a, b = a + 1, b + 1`

You can either use multiple statements, one per table row, or a single statement where all the values in the left column go on one side of the `=` and all the values in the right column go on the other side.

This works only for `=` though. Your idea `a, b += 1` firstly wouldn't work for the same reason `a, b = 0` doesn't (there is only one right-hand side value), but `a, b += 1, 1` unfortunately also doesn't work, just because Python doesn't support this concept. `+` with tuples would concatenate them into a larger tuple, not add each of their elements (`(1, 2) + (3, 4)` is `(1, 2, 3, 4)` and not `(4, 6)`).

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like a list of "how to update each variable" (variables to the left, formulas to the right).

```
a, b = a+1, b+1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in 1 line here is what you can do.. `a,b=0` is not the right way , it should have been `a=b=0` or `a,b=0,0`

```
a=b=0
a+=1;b+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to apply your increment or other operation

```
a,b=0,0

a, b = map( lambda x : x+1, [a,b])
```

output

```
1,1
```

Comment: Upvoted because it’s an interesting approach. But in *no way* a sign to advocate its use in production code.